# preg_match issue

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to grab numeric value(ie 105) using preg_match from html page, please check my html code following...

```
<p>
                External Backlinks
            </p>
            <p style="font-size: 150%;">
                <b>105</b>
            </p>
```

And i have using following regex...

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/test.html';

preg_match('#<p>External Backlinks</p><p style="font-size: 150%;"><b>([0-9\.]+)#', file_get_contents($url), $matches);

echo $matches[1];
```

But its not returning correct value, please help to fix up the above regex. thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1163867

Comment: For HTML, don't use *regex*, use *xpath*. Xpath are "regular" expressions for HTML/XML, e.g. `//p[@style="font-size: 150%;"]/b`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recommend using regex to parse HTML. Use a [DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) instead. [Read this rant for more information about why :)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

To answer your question. Here's a working regex for your example:

```
<p>[^E]*External Backlinks[^<]*<\/p>[^<]*<p style="font-size: ?150%;">[^<]*<b>(\d+)<\/b>[^<]*<\/p>
```

It's ugly, but it works... **Don't use it.**

```
preg_match('#<p>[^E]*External Backlinks[^<]*<\/p>[^<]*<p style="font-size: ?150%;">[^<]*<b>(\d+)<\/b>[^<]*<\/p>#', file_get_contents($url), $matches);

echo $matches[1];
```

**Output:**

```
105
```

The problem with your regex was that it didn't account for the whitespaces in the HTML source, and you didn't escape your slashes.

If the source looked something like this:

```
<p>External Backlinks</p><p style="font-size: 150%;"><b>105</b></p>
```

Yours would have worked, however not very robust. (Tho I guess one could argue using regex to parse HTML is never very robust.)